# Create laravel link based on route

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a link if the route is not the current route, however I'm getting an error when I try to include the link.
In my header blade:

```
    <a class="{{ Route::is('start') ? 'active' : '' }}"
  href="{{ URL::route('start') }}">Start</a>
```

In my web.php:

```
Route::get('/start', 'Start');
```

I'm getting the error:
Route [start] not defined. (View: /var/app/current/resources/views/include/header.blade.php)

My start route works if I go to myurl/start, but when I add it to my header it throws the error.  I ultimately want to only display the link on non-start route pages.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you in?

Comment: Follow [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes) how to set route.

Comment: Laravel version is 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to apply a "named route" for your route. I'm leaving you a link here below:

[Named Routes in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

In your route above this would become `Route::get('/start', 'Start')->name('start')'`

Notice the `->name('start')` at the end. Then you'll be able to reference the route just by its name.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error caused by the difference of the first character between "start" and "Start".

In web.php, you use 'Start' while in blade file is 'start'. Please correct it and check again.

Hope it works well